# Iterating over all elements of a page-object

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I have a search filter. I need to be able to check that all fields on the page are there and contain values (if they are select boxes).

I've used the MethodFinder gem to successfully do this, but I was wondering if there is any way with just the PageObject gem.

```
require 'methodfinder'

class BasicSearchFilter
  include PageObject

  text_field(:facility_name, :id => "facility-name")
  text_field(:queue, :id => "queue")
  select_list(:from, :id => "from")
  button(:continue, :id => "continue")

  def get_search_filter_elements
    methods = MethodFinder.find_in_class_or_module('BasicSearchFilter', '.*_element$')
    elements = []
    methods.each do |method|
      elements << send(method)
    end
  end
end
```

I've successfully used the above, but now I'm unable to use the page object methods which I would like to do. I would like to be able to somehow hand a list of valid "elements" which is just the PageObject version of the elements.

**Edit**: So it turns out that something extremely fishy is going on. 
I have a RSpec test grabbing the fields from the class above. It looks like this:

```
it "the basic filter dropdowns should not contain duplicate values" 
  on_page(BasicSearchFilter).get_search_filter_elements.each do |element|
    if element.tag_name == "select"
      p element
      puts "a select tag #{element}"
    end
  end
end
```

Now according to documentation the your_element_element command should return the watir element. Which is happening once. The second puts is somehow changing back to a PageObject object. I now have literally no clue what is happening. Here is some of the output from the above.

```
#<Watir::Select:0x4c6bdfa4 located=true selector={:id=>"facility-name", :tag_name=>"select"}>
a select tag #<PageObject::Elements::SelectList:0x3101538>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Getting All Elements**

While the page-object-gem does not have a method to get all elements, you could do it using plain Ruby. The following would give you the same results as your current method (assuming MethodFinder works as expected).

```
  def get_search_filter_elements
    element_methods = self.class.instance_methods(false).find_all{ |m| m =~ /_element$/ }
    elements = element_methods.collect{ |m| self.send(m) }
  end
```

**Iterating Over Elements**

Iterating over the elements returned by `get_search_filter_elements` is done as you did. However, there are a couple of things regarding your observations.

The `your_element_element` method returns the PageObject element (not the Watir element). This can be seen by outputting the class of the elements returned:

```
page.get_search_filter_elements.each{ |e| puts e.class }
#=> PageObject::Elements::TextField
#=> PageObject::Elements::TextField
#=> PageObject::Elements::SelectList
#=> PageObject::Elements::Button
```

The output of having the Watir element and then the PageObject element is not because the element has changed types. It is always the PageObject element. The output changes because you do `p` vs `puts`. When you `p` an object the `.inspect` method is outputted, where as when you `puts` an object the `.to_s` method is outputted. Given the way that the PageObject elements are written, `.to_s` gives information about the PageObject element, while the `.inspect` gives information about the native element (ie Watir or Selenium).

```
page.queue_element.to_s
#=> <PageObject::Elements::TextField:0x3851ca0>

page.queue_element.inspect
#=> #<Watir::TextField:0x1d58cb4 located=false selector={:id=>\"queue\", :tag_name=>\"input or textarea\", :type=>\"(any text type)\"}>
```

**Converting to Native Element**

If you actually want to iterate over the Watir elements (ie you want to call a method not supported by the PageObject), you use the `element` method. For example, the following iterates over the elements as Watir elements:

```
page.get_search_filter_elements.each{ |e| puts e.element.class }
#=> Watir::TextField
#=> Watir::TextField
#=> Watir::Select
#=> Watir::Button
```